# Trying to add .rvmrc to ignore, its not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rvm

So I modified my .rvmrc to what I need on my server, commit to git and pushed to origin.

Then I added .rvmrc to my .gitignore, but when I do a git status it shows the file has been modified.

I'm trying to fix it so it has my local settings now since the master has the server's version, and I don't want it to pickup the change I made to my local rvm settings since I added it to my .gitignore.

Comment: it's recommended that you track rvmrc in your VC

Answer (score 6):

From the [Git Documentation at Kernel.org](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> A `gitignore` file specifies intentionally untracked files that git should ignore. Files already tracked by git are not affected.

The solution follows:

> To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use `git rm --cached.`

I would do this:

```
$ git rm --cached .rmvrc
```

and try again.

Comment: if its untracked, will it still keep what's on the server?

Comment: Untracked files are those that would not get synced with remote repository while performing git operation. And yes, until you remove it from repository using 'git rm filename', it will be there.

Comment: Blankman: Is my answer accepted? I'd be happy if you accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged .rvmrc
```